# Cordova - Websockets doesn't seem to be working at all

Tags: cordova, web, websocket, phonegap-plugins

Our web application uses websockets, and in **cordova run browser** as well as on **android** ( through an iframe ), websockets doesn't not seem to be working at all.

This seems quite strange, so I am quite sure I can enable it somehow.

Anyone got any info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Cordova Plugin for websocket implementation.
I am using
https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android
in my Sample Cordova application and have been able to successfully do websocket connection.

Comment: I seem to have some other local related issue. I am able to connect to websocket.org and get a response, but not to the one on my server for some reason.